# Log paylod of JMS message that sent using spring JmsTemplate with domain object - ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am using ActiveMQ as a JMS provider, and spring-jms as JMS-producer.

When I send a JMS message to the broker as javax.jms.TextMessage, the payload of the message is logged in ActiveMq logs (\data\activemq.log). So if I send "abc" as a TextMessage, I see also in ActiveMq logs 'text = abc'.

When I send the message as one of my domain model objects, using spring JmsTemplate.convertAndSend method, the payload is not logged as the toString() of the domain model object in ActiveMQ logs. It is logged as a reference to an Object.

How can the domain model object be logged as its toString() in ActiveMq log?

Comment: MDB is in my world MessageDrivenBean and a JEE concept of JMS listener deployed as an EJB. btw what logs

Comment: You are right. I updated the question.